# Is "it holds that" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

One can clearly say "He holds that A=B", meaning "he strongly believes that A=B".
But can one say impersonally, in a scientific text, "It holds that A=B" or "There holds A=B" if one means "It is true that A=B"?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a phrase that can convey the notion of proving a theory, for example, "If it can be proved that Smith was in the building at 3pm, then it holds that he had time to steal the turnip and still be at his desk by 3:05"

Answer (score 0):

Well, *it holds that A = B* is fine.  *It holds*, in such a context, is impersonal, just as *it seems that* is an impersonal use.

But when it comes to *Jane holds that A = B*, the verb *holds* is being used in a different way.  It is equivalent to *believes* or *asserts* or perhaps *holds strongly* that A = B.

But then there is this second use of *hold*, where the verb is used **intransitively**.

> Attacked relentlessly by overwhelming forces, the line *held* or *held firm*.

This intransitive usage is common in both mathematics.  So, for example, we hold that

> If A = B and B = C, then A = C

If anyone doubted that claim, we can provide a *reductio ad absurdum* to show that if my claim is untrue, then A does not equal A, which is a self-contradiction.  So

The proposition that I hold  does, *hold*.  But this use usually (perhaps only) applies to arguments (in the logical or mathematical sense).  Ordinary truth claims like “it is raining” Re not said to *hold*, even though we **can** say “Once many people held that the earth was flat.”