# "It holds+statement"

Tags: grammaticality

In some of the mathematical papers I've encountered sentences like "It holds A>B.". I have a feeling that this is far from being grammatically correct, but I would appreciate a confirmation (or negation) by native English speakers, in order to have a reference.

This is similar, but in my opinion a bit more striking than "It holds that A>B.", cf.
[ELU: Is "it holds that" correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/474026/is-it-holds-that-correct)
[Mathematics: Is there a better alternative to the phrase 'it holds that'?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432039/is-there-a-better-alternative-to-the-phrase-it-holds-that/940045)

Comment: I agree. You need _that_ in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It's grammatically correct if you omit the *that* and this is often done in math; however, I suggest you keep it.

> ...which implies that in these regions holds [equation].
>
> ... we observe that it holds [equation]
>
> Now, since it holds [equation] [ref](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=9392002) (an IEEE publication)

> ...for every pair...it holds [equation] [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mathematical_Foundations_of_Computer_Sci/c_8WNtONOxAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22It%20holds%20k%22&pg=PA534&printsec=frontcover)

> Then it holds [equation]  [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Recent_Advances_In_Information_Science_A/o-2xDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22It%20holds%20k%22&pg=PA149&printsec=frontcover)

> Obviously, it holds [equation] [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Principles_and_Practice_of_Constraint_Pr/cKZCnHwuAnMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22It%20holds%20n%22&pg=PA744&printsec=frontcover)

---

We don't always see *that* after *it holds* and *it follows*:

> Note that in our structure, Bob knows whether p3 holds each state
> (i.e. if it **holds he knows** it and if it doesn't **hold he knows**
> the negation of it).  [N. Gal-Oz and P. R. Lewis; *Trust Management
> XII*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Trust_Management_XII/fLdiDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22It%20holds%20he%20knows%22&pg=PA121&printsec=frontcover)

> It **holds he** must be free to earn, spend, to save, to accumulate
> property that may give protection in old age and to loved ones.
> [Herbert Hoover in *Gateway to Citizenship*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gateway_to_citizenship/WWjt3DobOmkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22It%20holds%20he%22&pg=PA64&printsec=frontcover)

> The only things in Hume's system that **he holds we** cannot
> misrepresent are those that are 'immediately present' to the mind.
> [Donald Rutherford; *Oxford Studies in Early Modern Philosophy, vol.
> X*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Oxford_Studies_in_Early_Modern_Philosoph/R7EzEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22he%20holds%20we%20cannot%22&pg=PA202&printsec=frontcover)

> But **he holds we** cannot now silence the apprehension that there may
> be one. [G. H. Howison; *The Limits of Evolution*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Limits_of_Evolution/CnUFAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22he%20holds%20we%20cannot%22&pg=PA162&printsec=frontcover)

> It is true that if **he holds we** must deal with poetry after this
> fashion, it is because he sees ambitious possibilities in poetry, and
> conceives getting the most out of a poem in a way all his own. [John
> Constable; *I. A. Richards and His Critics V10*](http://I%20wouldn%27t%20go%20out%20of%20my%20way%20to%20omit%20that.%20I%27m%20wondering%20if%20publishers/editors%20have%20come%20to%20accept%20it.%20This%20needs%20more%20research.)

> Ethical naturalism is non-reductive in the strong sense that **it
> holds we** cannot move from the 'is' of empirical science to the
> 'ought' of moral theory. [Tom Angier; *The Cambridge Companion to
> Natural Law Ethics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Cambridge_Companion_to_Natural_Law_E/wC2xDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22It%20holds%20we%20cannot%22&pg=PA98&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Yes, however none of the authors (in the math papers) seem to be native English speakers. _It holds_+statement and _it follows_+statement feel like they need _that_, because if one was to personify _it_, then the meaning would become different. The next example which you give is much less controversial (Trust management). In the last one (Gateway...) I think that _it_ = _liberty_, but that might actually be a fair evidence for the correctness of _it holds X_.

Comment: Still, given the fact that both you and Lawrence said at some point that it sounds odd/is incorrect, I am not yet convinced :).

Comment: I wouldn't go out of my way to omit *that*. I'm wondering if math publishers/editors have come to accept it. I've added some examples.

Comment: The examples you added all have in common a definite subject, who/which believes in the subsequent statement. I hold that this is slightly different. As for the scientific publishers, I am afraid that the editorial work is often being not very scrupulous.

Comment: It is true that the word 'that' is often dispensable.  Possibly , it is on its way out.  The reason is probably that its omission often makes no difference.  "It's obvious you're annoyed with me." makes perfectly good sense, as does "it was such a pity you couldn't come.'  Personally, I would use 'that' after it holds' because in logic as in maths there should be a barrier between the proposition at issue and the statement that it is true, or false, or a theorem....

Comment: @ajr I've add an example from an IEEE-published paper that uses the construction without *that* in many places (yet also uses it with *that* in a couple of places). I doubt the IEEE has a sloppy editing process.